# Navigate to another screen and delete data in previous screen in one click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I want to delete data from room database and navigate to the MainScreen. When I try to do it in this way my app crashes, but data are deleted. I also tried to use `delay()` in the coroutine but then data are not deleted

```
BottomMenu(
    tournamentOption = "END TOURNAMENT",
    deleteButton = true,
    deleteTournament = {
        scope.launch {
            viewModel.deleteTournament(tournament)
        }
        navigate(navController, Screen.MainScreen)
    },
    action = { navigate(navController, Screen.MainScreen) },
)
```

**delete function:** https://github.com/DawidSiudeja/Tournament/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/tournamentapp/TournamentViewModel.kt

**EDIT**

I am in the Tournament view and I want to give the user the option to delete the tournament he is currently in, but when I delete this tournament, the tournament is deleted, but the application does not manage to move the user to the next view, so the application does not know what to display and crashes

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.tournamentapp, PID: 15034
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: NullPointerException are normally easy to debug. Did you check what's null?

Comment: It's happend when i use deleteTournament function. I wants to delete a tournament while in the tournament view and navigate do MainScreen.

Comment: My function deleting specify tournament corecttly, but before navigate to next screen, app is crashed

Comment: you need to post the entire error. It looks like you haven't set the viewModel variable

Answer (score 0):

Without the error message it's hard to tell what might be wrong. It could be because of the instance of the viewmodel no longer exists for that context, so maybe you could ask if the activity !isFinishing
By the way, you shouldn't use `scope.launch` inside views. That responsibility is handled by the viewmodel.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.tournamentapp, PID: 15034 java.lang.NullPointerException.  It's happend when i use deleteTournament function. I wants to delete a tournament while in the tournament view and navigate do MainScreen. My function deleting specify tournament corecttly, but before navigate to next screen, app is crashed